# Adding a foreign key contraint on a table with data

Tags: mysql

I'm wondering if it's possible to add a foreign key contraint on a table that already has data. I'm have a table **Suppliers** and a table **Ingredients**

When I try to add a constraint as follows:

[image]

I'm getting the following error

```
MySQL said: Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`blackfisk_relations`.`#sql-223_37`, CONSTRAINT `ingredients_supplier_id_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`supplier_id`) REFERENCES `suppliers` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to add a constraint to a table with data in it, the data must satisfy the constraint (or what would be the point of adding a constraint, if the data didn't have to satisfy it?)

Your options:

- You can remove the references to the foreign key that don't exist.
- You can add the keys in the foreign key table so the references do exist.

(Some DBMS allow a constraint to be added with NOCHECK specified, which means the constraint will be added, but won't be applied to existing data - only new data and changes to existing data. I don't know if MySql allows this - SQL Server and Oracle do. If MySql does, you may have to script it, rather than using a GUI option.)

Comment: Maybe the best way to find the faulty ones is to write a left join query? right?

Comment: Yes - if you want to find which ones are missing, a left outer join, so you keep the entries from the left table - and you can put a condition in the WHERE clause such that Supplier IS NULL - that will show you all, and only, the missing ones.

Comment: I'm confused. Which table would the right one then? haha

Comment: When you do a LEFT OUTER JOIN, it looks like this:

SELECT x FROM table1 LEFT OUTER JOIN table2 ON table1.col1 = table2.col1 

Table1 is left, Table2 is right

Comment: (I realise you may be joking, but since RIGHT joins exist, I thought it should be clarified.)

Comment: I wasn't joking! Haha thanks I'll see what I can do with your info.

Answer (score 1):

Of course you can, just ensure that the values of the foreign key exists on the referenced table, otherwise you will have to create all the missing values or changing their value to null

good luck

Answer (score 0):

If you have record against each primary key in table where you are creating foreign key then you can try to alter table.

Your error shows you have a record in table which does not exist as primary key in other table. This is preventing you from altering table.